# How much battery does a Suspend To RAM wakeup process consume

Tags: memory, battery, sleep, suspend

Let's assume I want to build a mobile embedded computer (something running on batteries and a display and Linux). This system could receive notifications at any time via the internet. It's enough to check for notifications every 10-15 seconds. I know that we can schedule a wakeup from RAM.

My question therefore is, will constantly waking up from RAM lower the battery usage or are there some heavy wakeup mechanisms going on which would even more drain the battery? Would it make sense to regularily wake up, check for notifications and then suspend again?

Comment: If you have an interval of 10-15 seconds to wake up and sleep it probably doesn't make sense. The savings would probably be minimal since the wakeup and sleep are usually not CPU throtteled.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO
When Hybernate, every 10-15 sec:

- Save RAM to persistent storage (on hybernate)
- BIOS post test (on wake)
- Load RAM from persistent storage (on wake)

When suspend:

- Keep RAM powered and refreshed

**UPD: Conclusion**

When wake every 15 seconds, very possible sleep win over hybernate in energy saving.

Comment: Excuse me, but that doesn't make sense to me. Of course hibernating would free the RAM from consuming power, but this process would heavily use the disk which consumes a much energy than the RAM. The whole data of (let's say) 1GB has to be copied to the disk just to copy it back to the RAM 15 seconds later. I think, your answer should be the other way around. It indeed makes sense to hibernate when you are sleeping longer and not keep the RAM powered.

Comment: Sorry. I miss conclusion. Look UPD